# Unspecified DNS error

Tags: domain-name-system

I run ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de, which is a public mirror serving (among other projects) Debian Linux files. Debian regularly checks mirror servers, and often experiences DNS issues for this host. I don't see what could be wrong with the DNS setup. The server is very active and I haven't received any other DNS related issue report. Sadly, I don't have any more details than that.

- Hostname ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
- IPv4 / A record 137.226.34.46
- IPv6 / AAAA record 2a00:8a60:e012:a00::21
- ftp2.de.debian.org is an alias / CNAME for ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de

Errors reported by Debian: https://mirror-master.debian.org/status/mirror-info/ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de.html

Previous discussion: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1021002

```
$ dig ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de

; <<>> DiG 9.18.19-1~deb12u1-Debian <<>> ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40623
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de. 366 IN  A   137.226.34.46

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
halifax.rwth-aachen.de. 885 IN  NS  dns-2.dfn.de.
halifax.rwth-aachen.de. 885 IN  NS  dns-1.dfn.de.
halifax.rwth-aachen.de. 885 IN  NS  zs2.rz.rwth-aachen.de.
halifax.rwth-aachen.de. 885 IN  NS  zs1.rz.rwth-aachen.de.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 185.12.64.1#53(185.12.64.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sat Jan 20 22:51:35 CET 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 154
```

What's wrong with the DNS setup and what kind of issue could trigger the warnings seen in Debian's system?

Comment: What is the TTL?

Comment: It's 600 as returned from the four authoritative DNS servers

Comment: I wouldn't be anywhere near a service where that is considered a good idea. What other kooky stuff are they doing.

Comment: Plain English please?

Comment: I guess 600 is too low, which might be related to an IP change (around a decode ago...). I just asked the powers in charge to increase the TTL, thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the TTL from 600 (10 minutes) to 86400 (24 hours) seemed to have fixed this. I don't know what exactly went wrong, though. Thanks a lot to Greg Askew for pointing me at this misconfiguration!

Comment: TTL of just 600 seconds is just a too low value. A world wide propagation of a DNS name may take up more time than just 600 seconds. A DNS name should mostly be a constant. PS doing **fast** load balancing using the DNS system is bad practice